# How does gaussian convution stacking work?

Tags: gaussian

If I first convolve an image with a Gaussian filter with σ = 1, and then convolve
the output of that image with a Gaussian with σ = 2

Does this give the same effect as convolving the original image with σ = 3?

Answer (score 1):

[From this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables), you can get:

[image]

So for your example, $\sigma_X = 1$ and $\sigma_Y = 2$. The result has a standard deviation of $\sigma_Z = \sqrt{\sigma^2_X + \sigma^2_Y} = \sqrt{1 + 4} = \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Isn't $\sigma$ standard deviation rather than variance, which would be $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Yes!  I'd started writing it out in terms of $\sigma^2_Z$ and then changed it when I wrote the formula. Thanks for the correction! Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier transform of a Gaussian $e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$ is another Gaussian with inverse scale, $e^{-\omega^2\sigma^2/2}$. And the product of two Gaussians is a Gaussian with the sum of the parameters.

Hence, two convolutions with $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ amount to a single convolution with

$$\sigma^2=\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2$$

In your example, $\sigma=\sqrt5$.